# Open mail template in excel via vba and fill template with excel data

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I need some help using excel for filling a mail template.
My problem right now is how to open the template with a macro 
I wrote this:

```
Sub OpenMail()

    Open "L:\Projekte\Abteilung\Projekt\Vorlage_deutsch" For Input As #1

End Sub
```

Running this macro it throws me an error that says data can not be found.
Is there a way to save the template in excel directly instead of trying to open it from the computer?
Also if you have any idea on how to fill the email with the data of my rows in excel that would be really helpful! 
Thanks!!

Comment: and whats the accurate extension of an office template ? i used pst but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code to open an outlook mail template.

```
Sub CreateMailInExcel()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
''Debug.Print (olApp.ProductCode)
Set Msg = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\Test\untitled.oft")
Msg.Display
'Set Msg = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The extension of outlook mail template is .oft

You need to set reference to Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library.

Answer (score 0):

Below sub is simple type a mail with data from excel cells. You have to adjust codes for your need.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMail()
Dim sendTo As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strMail as String

'Ad referrence ---> Microsoft Outlook 12.0 object library

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strMail = Range("A1")  ' Email address in A1 cell
strBody = Range("B1")  ' Subject text in B1 cell
strSubject = Range("C1") ' Message body in C1 cell

        With OutMail
            '.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFile.pdf"
            .To = strMail
            .Subject = strSubject 
            .HTMLBody = strBody
            .Display 'Show mail message.
            '.Send  'Direct send
        End With
'    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
'    Application.SendKeys "%s"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!
But I dont wanna send the mail because there ist some input that is individual to every mail. I just wanna fill in some information then let the user put the rest inand send it... I also have to use a specific email template... :/

Comment: I have provided you just a simple logic. Edit it as your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you maybe describe your logic in a few sentences? I am really new to vba.. sorry                                                  have a good day :)

Comment: Suppose you want to type a mail with some pre-defined data like specific sentence for subject, specific paragraph for mail body. And then you want to edit few data in subject and body. So, you can store those predefined texts in excel cells and open a new mail with those texts, Then you can add/edit user's text and send mails.