# Sending Excel row in Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

My Excel sheet contains the task name, assigned person, assigned person email address, due date.

On the first day of every month I want to check the sheet and send emails automatically through Outlook when the task is overdue.

I want to send only their task.

The codes I found will share the whole sheet not specific rows.

Comment: Have a look into this for basic idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589730/5514747 Then do some google search, you will get lot of codes to send mail from Excel via Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

example:
values stored starting at row 2

column A - task name

column B - person name

column C - email

column D - due date

```
Sub CheckOverdue()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim xcell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'last row with value in column D with due dates
    lastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'loop thru each due date in column D
    For Each xcell In sht.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
        If Not IsDate(xcell) Then
            MsgBox "Error in value of due date in " & xcell.Address(False, False)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Date > CDate(xcell) Then
            With CreateObject("outlook.application").createitem(0)
                .To = sht.Range("C" & xcell.Row)
                .Subject = "Overdue"
                .Body = "Hi, " & sht.Range("B" & xcell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Your task " & sht.Range("A" & xcell.Row) & " is overdue"
                .Display ' change to .Send after testing to automatically send the email
            End With
        End If
    Next xcell
End Sub
```